# Adding Index in Create Table Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anyway way you can do this?  I know there are separate statements to explicitly state this but is there a way you can specify an index in the create table statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE lookup
(id INT, INDEX USING BTREE (id))
```